# How to unit test with a file upload in mocha

Tags: node.js, express

I have an app built on Express.js and I'd like to test the file upload functionality. I'm trying to reproduce the object parsed to req.files (when using express.bodyParser middleware). How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this directly in Mocha but it's a bit tricky. Here's an example posting an image:

```
var filename = 'x.png'
  , boundary = Math.random()

request(app)
  .post('/g/' + myDraftGallery._id)
  .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary)
  .write('--' + boundary + '\r\n')
  .write('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="'+filename+'"\r\n')
  .write('Content-Type: image/png\r\n')
  .write('\r\n')
  .write(fs.readFileSync('test/'+filename))
  .write('\r\n--' + boundary + '--')
  .end(function(res){
    res.should.have.status(200)
    done()
  })
```

The *name* parameter of Content-Disposition is what your file will be accessible as via req.files (so req.files.image for my example)
You can also use an array value like this: name="images[]" and your file(s) will be available via an array, e.g: req.files.images[0]

Also if you're not already using it you should have a look at this (makes mocha/express testing a ~bit~ easier):
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/test/support/http.js

**Edit**: Since express 3-beta5, express uses supertest. To look at the old http.js code look here: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3.0.0beta4/test/support/http.js
Or simply move over to supertest..

Answer (score 51):

Here is an example of how you would do it with [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) module.

```
var should = require('should'),
    supertest = require('supertest');
var request = supertest('localhost:3000');

describe('upload', function() {
    it('a file', function(done) {
       request.post('/your/endpoint')
              .field('extra_info', '{"in":"case you want to send json along with your file"}')
              .attach('image', 'path/to/file.jpg')
              .end(function(err, res) {
                  res.should.have.status(200); // 'success' status
                  done();
              });
    });
});
```

Comment: When I try this, req.files is still undefined.  I am using bodyParser and no ENOENT errors for the file.

Comment: As @SteveN mentioned, req.files is undefined. I was able to get the files out only using "form.parse" from the multiparty npm library, which returned the files field as 
files { [attachment: {<file data>}] } Nothing else I tried worked.

Comment: Here's the github issue. I posted how I am getting around it there: https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/47

Answer (score 12):

```
var expect = require('expect.js');
supertest = require('supertest');
var request = supertest('localhost:3000');

describe('create album', function () {
    it('valid ', function (done) {
        request.post('/albums')
            .set('Authorization', 'Token eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.IjkxMTg3NTk1ODg2MCI.gq32xfcOhv5AiZXJup5al1DGG0piyGWnrjZ5NouauCU')
            .field('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
            .field('name', 'moni')
            .field('description', 'Nature+Pics')
            .field('caption', 'nature')
            .field('contacts', '["' + 911354971564 + '","' + 919092888819 + '"]')
            .field('dimensions', '{"photo1":{"height": 10, "width": 10}, "photo2":{"height": 20, "width": 20}, "photo3":{"height": 20, "width": 20}, "photo4":{"height": 20, "width": 20}, "photo5":{"height": 20, "width": 20}}')
            .attach('photo1', '/home/monica/Desktop/pic/1.jpeg')
            .attach('photo2', '/home/monica/Desktop/pic/2.jpeg')
            .attach('photo3', '/home/monica/Desktop/pic/3.jpeg')
            .attach('photo4', '/home/monica/Desktop/pic/4.jpeg')
            .attach('photo5', '/home/monica/Desktop/pic/5.jpeg')
            .end(function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 6):

Changing attach('image') to attach('file') will solve the problem of req.files.file not defined.

```
var should = require('should'),
    supertest = require('supertest');
var request = supertest('localhost:3000');

describe('upload', function() {
    it('a file', function(done) {
       request.post('/your/endpoint')
              .field({field1: 'xxx', field2: 'yyy'})
              .attach('file', 'path/to/file.jpg')
              .end(function(err, res) {
                  res.should.have.status(200) // 'success' status
                  done()
              });
    });
});
```

Comment: actually doens't solve it for me, still not getting `req.files.file`

Comment: @Name Game does /path/to/file.jpg have to be an absolute path on your dev machine, thus the test would not portable to another machine? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Just came across this module by TJ: https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using zombie.js https://github.com/assaf/zombie , it creates a virtual browser for testing with basic functionality. It can attach a file to a specific input field and supports cookies and sessions

related gist : https://gist.github.com/764536

Answer (score 1):

If using [request promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) you can simply do this, sending formData is built into it:

```
    var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: base + '/api/image/upload',
      formData: {
        someField: 'someValue',
        anotherField: 'anotherValue',
        file: {
          // path to image
          value: fs.createReadStream('./testImg.png'),
          options: {
            filename: 'testImg.png',
            contentType: 'image/png'
          }
        }
      }
    };
    let resp;
    try {
      resp = await request.post(options);
      body = JSON.parse(resp);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      resp = e.response;
      code = resp.statusCode;
      body = JSON.parse(resp.body);
    }
    // access what is returned here, check what needs to be
    assert.equal(code, 200, 'Status: ' + code + ': ' + body.error);
    assert.equal(body.success, true);
    assert.exists(body.image);
```

Comment: As an added on note, this is different from a usual file upload since it attaches it to req.body. If your backend code is looking for req.files or similar, then this may not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Directory structure:

```
    tests/
    ├── consts/
    │   └── payloads/
    │       └── cvs_upload_tests/
    │            └── file_with_invalid_column_name.csv
    │
    ├── controllers/
    │   └── controllerTest.js
    │
    └── .../
```

controllerTest.js

```
const path = require('path');
const basedir = path.resolve('./tests');    
    await chai.request(app)
                .post(`${APP_ROOT_PATH}/cms/xxx/xxx-xxx?type=xxx`)
                .set('Authorization', API_KEY)
                .set('API_KEY', API_KEY)
                .attach('file', `${basedir}/consts/payloads/cvs_upload_tests/file_with_invalid_column_name.csv`)
                .then((response) => {
                  assert.strictEqual(response.body.error.message, 'Invalid file');
                  assert.strictEqual(response.status, 400);
                });
```

I use

```
"chai": "^4.2.0",
"chai-http": "^4.3.0",
"mocha": "^6.2.1",
```