# How to test multipart/form-data using chai

Tags: express, mocha.js, multipartform-data, chai

I have a signup endpoint in my project which works fine. However, I added profile image uploading field to the inputs to allow users upload images.
This works fine, my problem is with testing.

I'm trying to test using `chai` but I don't know how to parse image files to the `POST` request.

I discovered there's an `attach()` method which takes in file but how do I parse in the other fields.

Comment: you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19148688/9512447

or see there another examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120866/how-to-unit-test-with-a-file-upload-in-mocha

Comment: Thank you. I was able to resolve it using the page you suggested.